# Counting words, vowels, and consonants in Python using nested loops

Tags: python-3.x

My assignment is to write a program in Python that takes input from the user in the form of random words and phrases until the user types "The End." It then needs to give the number of consonants and vowels as well as the number of words typed up until the user ends the program. I have a basic understanding of what I need to do but I'm having trouble understanding how to use Nested loops in the program(required) and how to keep track of the vowels, consonants and words. We just learned about functions(main, etc.) and I think that is a good place to start on this. I understand if/elif/else statements very well and I'm certain they're needed in this as well.

This is the sample given to us.

```
Hi! I count vowels and consonants! Please enter your words for counting. When you are done, enter “The end.”

Please enter a string: elephant

Please enter a string: house

Please enter a string: pacman

Please enter a string: I’m done

Please enter a string: The end

Please enter a string: 5

Thanks for entering your input!

Total number of vowels: 11

Total number of consonants: 14
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm a beginner at this and I'm having trouble keeping track of all the different techniques. I just need help getting this off the ground. Getting started has always been the hardest part for me.

Comment: Start by asking for `input`? :p

Comment: I got that. I should use a loop so that it keeps asking for strings until The End is entered. But how do I keep track of the c,v, and words?

Comment: Set some initial variables to `0`, then work out how many V, C, W's etc... to them before "The End"? (try starting with counting words - then add to it)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Comment: I suspect `Please enter a string: 5` should be `Total number of words: 5` and should come after `Thanks...`.

Comment: I would start by writing a function that takes this list `['elephant', 'house', 'pacman', "I'm done"] and returns (5, 11, 14).  Then worry about writing a function to produce a list from user input.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by setting all three counters to zero
2. Get input
3. If it's a word, add 1 to the word counter
4. Again, if it's a word, count the consonants and add that to the consonant counter
5. Again, if it's a word, count the vowels
6. If it wasn't a word (the end condition) then exit from the loop and finish up
7. Go back to step 2 and ask for another word
8. Finishing up: After all the words have been entered and counted, print the totals

You can write a function to count the vowels and/or consonants.

Try this:

```
import string

def count_consonants(in_string):
    a = len(in_string)
    b = len(string.translate(in_string, None, vowels)) #count again after removing vowels
    return a - b

vowels = "aeiou"
word = "elephant"

print string.translate(word, None, vowels)

print count_consonants(word)
```